# Angular ng-packagr custom package auto-generated paths issues

Tags: angular, ng-packagr, angular-library

There is a custom library in our project. And the issue is when I run the command `ng build *package_name*` everything (classes and etc.) builds fine except paths in **functions**.

For example, it generates line

`export declare const selectState: import ("`**../../../AppFolder/ClientApp/node_modules/@ngrx/store/src/selector**`").foobar`

when correct path would be

`export declare const selectState: import ("`**../../AppFolder/ClientApp/node_modules/@ngrx/store/src/selector**`").foobar`

and everytime after I build the package I need to remove **../** in each path which is kind of annoying and takes a lot of time due to many changes made to the library.

Problem persists only with this **node_modules/@ngrx/store/src/selector**

Answer (score 0):

I have checked, the issue has been fixed in TypeScript 3.1.1